# sort and research with graph coredata

Tags: cosmicmind

My code is:

```
let risultato = DataManager.sharedInstance.graph.searchForEntity(
      properties: [(key: "tempo", value: "00:00:40.00",
          ("valore","decimi")])
```

But I want my result to satisfy both conditions is a so or no and.

How should I do this?

Also how can I do the sort the entity according to a key?

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter, Graph takes a programmatic approach, rather than writing complex queries. So the first thing would be to get the collection of data that you are looking for, which is done through `OR`. The `AND` is handled in the `filter`

```
let result = graph.searchForEntity(properties: [("valore", "decimi")]).filter { (entity: Entity) in
        return entity["tempo"] as? String == "00:00:40.00"
    }
```

For sorting, you can do this, since the result data structure is an Array

```
    let sorted: [Entity] = result.sort ({ $0["key"] as? String > $1["key"] as? String })

    let sorted: [Entity] = result.sort { (a: Entity, b: Entity) -> Bool in
        return a["key"] as? String > b["key"] as? String
    }
```

**FYI**

Also, you don't need a shared instance of Graph through `DataManager.sharedInstance`. Any instance of Graph will reference the same data. That is one of the benefits that Graph offers.